# Visual Studio - Show Methods in VB

Tags: visual-studio-2013

I'm new to Visual Studio and have a large file of VB6 code with many functions (whited out).  I thought if I pressed CTRL + SHIFT + C, I could see all the methods listed in the file.  Why is it blank?

[image]

Comment: What made you think ctrl+shift+c would do that?

Comment: Also, VB6 code is not going to compile, or be parsed correctly, in Visual Studio. You need to use the VB6 IDE (sorry).